# Dataframe Lookup function to return multiple matches

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, typeerror

I have two dataframes as follows:

```
Credits:

       ID  Account     Credits       Date
0     122     1234    30546.45 2017-02-16
1   40058     2345   200000.00 2019-04-04
2   53133     2345    30495.82 2019-09-12
3   91437     3456  1725000.00 2020-04-13
4  133686     4567   500000.00 2019-08-28
5  134792     4567  1448887.50 2019-11-22
6  135794     4567   400000.00 2020-02-04
7  137555     4567   500000.00 2020-08-10


Debits:

        ID  Account      Debits       Date
0    49020     7405   871140.57 2019-06-21
1    63274     9714  1725000.00 2020-04-13
2    64788     5351  1448887.50 2019-11-22
3    94443     5678  1725000.00 2020-04-15
4    92868     5678   525000.00 2020-03-27
5   123732     6789    30495.82 2019-09-13
6   125585     7890   200000.00 2019-04-04
7   138182     8901   930088.80 2019-12-31
8   137829     8901   700000.00 2019-12-09
9   135588     8901   200000.00 2019-04-04
10  143025     9012   500000.00 2019-08-28
11  143451     9012   500000.00 2020-08-10
12  143212     9012   400000.00 2020-02-04
```

(In reality both of these dataframes are hundreds of thousands of lines long, but I'm shortening them for this example.)

What I want is to go through each number amount in `Credits['Credits']` and find all corresponding amounts in `Debits['Debits']` that are within 3 days of the `Credit` date.

So the end result (in a new dataframe) should look like this:

```
CreditsMatch
     MatchID
0  N/A
1  [125585,135588]
2  123732
3  [63274,94443]
4  143025
5  64788
6  143212
7  143451
```

I've written this function:

```
def Match(SearchCr, SearchDate):
    if not pd.isnull(SearchCr):
        SearchDtLo = SearchDate - timedelta(3)
        SearchDtHi = SearchDate + timedelta(3)
        filt_Debits = []
        filt_Debits = Debits.query('Debits == @SearchCr and `Date` >= @SearchDtLo and `Date` <= @SearchDtHi and `Account` != @SearchAcct')
        Matchlist = filt_xferdbdf['ID'].tolist()        
        return Matchlist
```

It works fine if I run it on a single item in the list.

But when I try to apply it to the Credits column using this:

```
CreditsMatch['MatchID'] = Credits['Credits'].apply(lambda x: Match(x['Credits'], x['Date'], axis =1))
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

`Credits['Credits'].apply` will call the specified function once *per item in the series*. So `x` is a `float`, because `Credits['Credits']` contains floats.

Since you're trying to access `Credits['Credits']` and `Credits['Date']` in the function, it looks like you're trying to run that function *for each row*. To do that, call `apply` on the whole `Credits` dataframe, and not just the `Credits['Credits']` series.

Change this line:

```
CreditsMatch['MatchID'] = Credits['Credits'].apply(lambda x: Match(x['Credits'], x['Date'], axis =1))
```

To this:

```
CreditsMatch['MatchID'] = Credits.apply(lambda x: Match(x['Credits'], x['Date'], axis=1))
```

(`Credits['Credits'].apply` → `Credits.apply`)

Comment: Still no luck. Now it's saying "KeyError: 'Credits'"

Comment: Send the output of `print(Credits.head().to_dict())`